# What does "fight long odds" mean?

Tags: meaning

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/RBsY88Lir-A). It is at 2 minute and 42 second. Here is the context:

> A few of his sources contained mentions of Arthur, and some others were realistic accounts of battles and places. But many featured mythical hero es fighting **
>   ** with with the help of magic swords and sorcery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase is **fighting long odds**, that is, they were engaged in a battle in which their chances of winning were very small.

Compare:

> He might win the election, but it's a long shot.